# In which region of earth is the Garden of Eden located?

Tags: biblical-basis, genesis, eden

**Genesis 2:15(NIV)**

> The LORD God took the man and put him in the **Garden of Eden** to work it
>   and take care of it.

I'm curious to know, now, **in which which country is the Garden of Eden located?** (which is mentioned in Genesis)

Comment: The world was destroyed with flood, thus the renaming of the Rivers were just for historic proofs of the reality of the garden on earth. Who named the rivers those names? Was it God or man? What do those names of the rivers mean in the languages of those who claim the presence of Eden in their countries? That's how to get closer to the answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Per Genesis 2:

> 10 A river watering the garden flowed from Eden; from there it was separated into four headwaters. 11 The name of the first is the Pishon; it winds through the entire land of Havilah, where there is gold. 12 (The gold of that land is good; aromatic resin[d] and onyx are also there.) 13 The name of the second river is the Gihon; it winds through the entire land of Cush.[e] 14 The name of the third river is the Tigris; it runs along the east side of Ashur. And the fourth river is the Euphrates.

While Mesopatamia (i.e. Iraq) is where the Tigris & Euphrates are, the remaining two rivers (Gihon is in Israel, and the Pishon is, I believe unknown, though some scholars think it is the Nile) are not.

There are thus two possibilities:

1. The Flood altered where these rivers flowed
2. The location is not meant to be literal

In any event, the Flood probably did wipe out the Garden of Eden, and even if it didn't, there was an angel (in Genesis 3:24) who is guarding the entrance.

---

Update: For an interesting excursion into the idea of "mapping" Eden, check out this [article showing maps of Eden from 1914](http://bigthink.com/strange-maps/583-east-is-eden-adam-and-eves-chinese-garden?page=all).  They are highly speculative, but show the diversity of thought around where Eden might be.

Comment: So is the answer Iraq or Israel?

Comment: 3. The new rivers were named for older rivers   4. This is made up

Answer (score 6):

Assuming it was a literal garden in the physical world, and not a metaphor, it was most likely somewhere between the Tigris and Euphrates rivers, close to the border between modern day Iraq and Iran, or maybe the Eastern region of modern Turkey.

Just Googling for Tigris, Euphrates and Eden will give you more sources you can probably read in a lifetime :)

Answer (score 3):

John Sailhamer [proposes](http://www.desiringgod.org/blog/posts/sailhamers-view-of-creation) a rather novel idea in his book *Genesis Unbound*:

> The second chapter of Genesis provides a closer look at God's creation of the first human beings. We are told that God created them from the ground and put them in the garden of Eden to worship and obey God (not merely to work the garden and take care of it). The boundaries of that garden are the same as those of the promised land; thus the events of these chapters foreshadow the events of the remainder of the Pentateuch. God creates a people, He puts them into the land He has prepared for them, and He calls on them to worship and obey Him and receive His blessing.

I haven't read the book myself, but thinking about the Torah texts, it does solve a number of problems.  But the theory is *at least* as controversial as every other theory I know of.

Comment: Is the implication here that the Garden of Eden would be roughly equivalent to modern Israel?

Comment: @Caleb: That's correct, more or less.  I believe the idea is that the entire story of Genesis is the story of how the Promised Land came to be.  (But I have not read the book itself, so there may be more to it than that.)

Answer (score 3):

**Where was the Garden of Eden?**

*A river watering the garden flowed from Eden; from there it was separated into four headwaters. The name of the first is the Pishon; it winds through the entire land of Havilah, where there is gold. (The gold of that land is good; bdellium and onyx stone are also there.) The name of the second river is the Gihon; it winds through the entire land of Cush. The name of the third river is the Hiddekel [which is the Tigris]; it runs along the east side of [the city of] Ashur. And the fourth river is the Euphrates.*  (Genesis 2:10-14)

> The name "Eden" derives from the Akkadian "edinnu", from a Sumerian word "edin" meaning 'plain' or 'steppe', closely related to an Aramaic root word meaning 'fruitful, well-watered'.  (See Wikipedia aricle for the *Garden of Eden*.)

Of the four rivers, two, the Euphrates and the Tigris, are very well-known, and two, the Gihon and the Pishon, require some detective work.

The Pishon "winds through the entire land of Havilah where there is gold".

The land of "Havilah" is recorded seven times in the Old Testament: Genesis 2:11, 10:7, 10:29, 25:18; 1 Samuel 15:7; 1 Chronicles 1:9, 1:23.  What is written in Chronicles is very similar to Genesis 10. Genesis 25:18 is similar to 1 Samuel 15:7 which suggests Havilah is south of Judaea. Possibly Havilah covered a large arid region extending down from Sinai down the west coast of Arabia.

Some gold was being mined in Turkey in ancient times.  (The story of the king who accidently turned his daughter into gold is mythical, but King Midas was a real king of history who reigned in a region of Turkey.) I believe, apart from Turkey, the main place in the Middle East having gold deposits is in the west of Saudi Arabia.  An ancient mine is still in operation there at Mahd Adh Dhahab which means "cradle of gold".  The Saudi mining company, "Maaden", has a mine at Mansourah Massarah and in 2023 found other "massive" deposits in the same region, about half way between Madinah/Medina and Makkah/Mecca.  See
[https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/travel/travel-news/saudi-arabia-discovers-massive-gold-reserves-in-makkah-region/articleshow/106512074.cms#:~:text=Saudi%20Arabia%20recently%20announced%20the,Al%20Khurmah%20governorate%2C%20Makkah%20region](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/travel/travel-news/saudi-arabia-discovers-massive-gold-reserves-in-makkah-region/articleshow/106512074.cms#:%7E:text=Saudi%20Arabia%20recently%20announced%20the,Al%20Khurmah%20governorate%2C%20Makkah%20region).

Click here to see the location of these mines: [https://www.google.com/maps/place/Mansourrah+and+Massarah+Gold+Project+Ma'aden/@23.4268711,39.2425064,7z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x158d8fc1e69174a5:0xe6b6016c6fe7e13d!8m2!3d22.702773!4d42.698833!16s%2Fg%2F11hz6mm2qt?entry=ttu](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Mansourrah+and+Massarah+Gold+Project+Ma%27aden/@23.4268711,39.2425064,7z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x158d8fc1e69174a5:0xe6b6016c6fe7e13d!8m2!3d22.702773!4d42.698833!16s%2Fg%2F11hz6mm2qt?entry=ttu)

If Havilah is in the Middle East then this is the likely area.  A wadi runs from this region in western Arabia to Kuwait on the east coast.  In the west it is called Wadi Al Rummah or Ar Rummah, which disappears in the dunes at Buraidah.  In 1993 Egyptian-American NASA scientist Dr Farouq El Baz used ground-penetrating radar technologies to show the wadi continued under the sand and continued to the east side of the dune where it is known as Wadi Al Batin.  He showed it was the same wadi.  Under the sand it is now called Mistewy Wadi.

At one time in ancient times it is believed it was a large river: the wadi is more than a mile wide in places.  The wadi reaches Kuwait at Kuwait's western most tip and then mostly forms the border between Kuwait and Iraq before entering the Persian Gulf north east of Kuwait City.

[image: Researchgate.net map showing location of wadi (mistakenly) calling the whole length "Wadi Al Batin"]

This is a map of wadis and river systems for Saudi Arabia and surrounding region.  Here, the whole wadi length is called Wadi Al Batin.

Some believe that "Cush" in Genesis 2 is neither Ethiopia nor the region of south west Saudi Arabia opposite Ethiopia: that the people of Cush may have been in another region in the Median mountains in early history; or that it is the Kassites who are intended.  (In support of the possibility that neither Ethiopia nor South West Saudi Arabia is intended, note Genesis 10:6-12: here Nimrod is a descendant of Cush who built cities in Mesopotamia, including Babel, Erech, Accad, Calneh (v10), and maybe Ninevah and more (v11).)

If this was the case then the four rivers would be:

[image: The proposed four rivers and location of the Garden of Eden]

But even if identity of the Gihon River is not certain, the confluence of three of the four rivers is fairly persuasive: the Garden of Eden was a real place, and it was here at the northern end of the Persian Gulf.  Today it is either covered by the shallow waters of the Persian Gulf or it is just to the north of the Gulf.

See Joel Kramer's very interesting youtube video "Searching for The Garden of Eden's Pishon River" here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwCdZ4CbA-E

The land of "Havilah" is recorded seven times in the Old Testament: Genesis 2:11, 10:7, 10:29, 25:18; 1 Samuel 15:7; 1 Chronicles 1:9, 1:23.

Comment: I am uncertain that there can be an answer but up-voted +1 for the very plausible and thorough research.

Answer (score 0):

Well I know that the Gihon River is all gone but a little portion of it left is located in Ethiopia, Africa and the Gihon River used to flow down the middle of the Red Sea gowing through the Sinai Peninsula to the Mediterranean Sea and down through Ethiopia, Africa. The Pison River actually ran kind of east to west across Saudia Arabia from the Red Sea to the Persian Gulf. The Pison runs smack down the middle of modern day Kuwait. and both the Hiddekel and the Euphrates both run through modern day Iraq but the Euphrates also goes through Syria but the Hiddekel goes through modern day Turkey. So the Garden of Eden is not in Iraq like they think it is. There is two possible places where the former location of Eden would be located either at the bottom of the Persian Gulf or the Mediterranean Sea. And that is where I think it is located.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you improve this answer by providing supporting evidence and references? http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer

Comment: Also, please take the time to capitalize according to standard English usage and maybe break up your post into paragraphs as appropriate. It is very difficult to read in this format.

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago (1988) I took an excursion in Turkey which I blew off at the time as ridicolous. I'm a veteran and was stationed in Sinop on the black sea. We took a very interesting bus ride to what the Hittites considered to be the remnants of the garden of Eden. I admit it sounded cheesy at the time but on that bus we experienced things and saw things that even 25 years later I cannot explain. It was beautiful and it was said to be unkept. On the way to the garden was carnage and death where people started getting irritable and shouting including myself. I said theatrics or perhaps gases from a tar pit can explain that? Then as we entered through a stone gate the climate and mood instantly changed. Lush fruit trees and picturesque waterfalls and streams.I tell my story but ironically I cannot find any evidence of where the actual location was then or now. It was in Turkey and within a 2.5 hr bus ride of Sinop for certain. After growing and understanding the bible and it's teachings 25 years later has given me renewed interest in my personal journey and why I was given the visions I've seen throughout my life so Happy hunting!!!! Some things are supernatural and I've accepted it.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are always happy to have new participants. Your story is interesting; thank you for sharing it. Please see [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808) . Also see the [about] and [help] pages. I hope to see you again.

Answer (score 0):

Most sources conclude that finding Eden would be just about impossible. That's aside from the fact that god placed an angel to guard it. That tells me god doesn't want us in there and that's assuming anything survived the flood [**Source**](http://www.icr.org/article/1208/).

Here is another source with information on Eden and some clues to location [**Insight**](http://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200001256). scroll down it's the last article.

Many believe that south of Van lake in modern day Turkey may have been the location of Eden. [**Source**](http://www.geocreationism.com/science/eden-lake-van-lake-urmia.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a question can't really be answered. All we can do is guess. John Calvin could not answers this and I know that I have no clue. When you factor in how the earth changed from Pangea to what we have today and then the changes the Flood would have caused no one can say for certain. But here are some links that talk about the Garden of Eden, Creation, and A map of Pangea. And two links for any who would like to venture into the Tanakh online. chabad.org is the better of the two if you just want to read the books of the Tanakh. Torah - The Pentateuch is part of the Tanakh (Jewish Bible).

[Where was the Garden of Eden Located?](http://www.answersingenesis.org/articles/nab3/where-was-eden)

[New Research Proves Single Origin Of Humans In Africa](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2007/07/070718140829.htm)

[Out of Africa or Out of Eden: Does Science Contradict the Bible?](http://www.godandscience.org/apologetics/humans_out_of_africa.html)

[Plate Tectonics - Pangaea Continent Maps](http://geology.com/pangea.htm)

[Mechon Mamre](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/)

[The Complete Tanach with Rashi's Commentary](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/63255/jewish/The-Bible-with-Rashi.htm)

Answer (score 0):

**In which region on earth is the Garden of Eden located?**

Ultimately, no one can be absolutely sure where the Garden of Eden was located. Exegetists have various points of view on this as well as some denominations have particular traditions on this subject matter. Even some Christian mystics have a particular point of view on where the Garden of Eden may be located.

[Mormon belief that the original Garden of Eden was located in Missouri.](https://www.fairlatterdaysaints.org/answers/Joseph_Smith/Prophet/Garden_of_Eden_in_Missouri)

Some put forth that the Garden was in Africa! [Garden of Eden in Africa: Humanity's first home traced to Botswana](https://news.sky.com/story/garden-of-eden-in-africa-humanitys-first-home-traced-to-botswana-study-11847991)

But what does Scriptures say about the location of Eden?

> 8 Now the Lord God had planted a garden **in the east**, in Eden; and there he put the man he had formed. 9 The Lord God made all kinds of trees grow out of the ground—trees that were pleasing to the eye and good for food. In the middle of the garden were the tree of life and the tree of the knowledge of good and evil.
>
> 10 **A river watering the garden flowed from Eden; from there it was separated into four headwaters. 11 The name of the first is the Pishon; it winds through the entire land of Havilah, where there is gold. 12 (The gold of that land is good; aromatic resin[d] and onyx are also there.) 13 The name of the second river is the Gihon; it winds through the entire land of Cush.[e] 14 The name of the third river is the Tigris; it runs along the east side of Ashur. And the fourth river is the Euphrates**.
>
> 15 The Lord God took the man and put him in the Garden of Eden to work it and take care of it. 16 And the Lord God commanded the man, “You are free to eat from any tree in the garden; 17 but you must not eat from the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, for when you eat from it you will certainly die.” [Genesis 2:8-17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%202%3A1-17&version=NIV)

As for myself it would be reasonable to exclude that America and Africa would not be the place where the Garden of Eden would be located as Genesis places the location **in the East**! If we hold to the ancient tradition that Moses wrote the first books of the Bible in Palestine, then it becomes obvious that it should have been located to the east of Jerusalem.

The location of the Garden of Eden is described in the Book of Genesis as the source of four tributaries. This is geographically impossible. The Tigris and the Euphrates, for example, which, by the way, did not merge in ancient times, were in Mesopotamia, while Kush is south of Egypt. Nevertheless  various suggestions have been made for its location: at the head of the Persian Gulf, in southern Mesopotamia, where the Tigris and Euphrates rivers run into the sea; and in Armenia.

> [image]
>
> Suggestions for the location of the Garden of Eden include the head of the Persian Gulf, as argued by Juris Zarins, in southern Mesopotamia (now Iraq and Kuwait) where the Tigris and Euphrates rivers run into the sea;nand in the Armenian Highlands or Armenian Plateau. British archaeologist David Rohl locates it in Iran, and in the vicinity of Tabriz, but this suggestion has not caught on with scholarly sources. - [Garden of Eden](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_of_Eden)

Moses seems to have known about the location of Eden. This knowledge existed as late as the Hebrew compilation of the Torah. Why is the Garden's location such a mystery today? **It is not impossible new rivers were named for older rivers!**

Interestingly enough, Josephus, in his ***Antiquities of the Jews***, identified the Pishon River with the Ganges River of India.

This all leads me to another possible location, yet albeit more on a mysterious mystic level.nwhere it be true or not I would like to add it in as a possibility to contemplate.

The mystic Catherine Emmerich in her Revelations, puts forth the possibility that the Garden of Eden is in the  Himalayans (India).

> Adam and Eve had been only one day in Paradise. I now see Paradise far, far off like a strip of land directly under the point of sunrise. When the sun rises, it mounts up from the right of that strip of land which lies east of the **Prophet Mountain** and just where the sun rises. It looks to me like an egg hanging over indescribably clear water which separates it from the earth. The **Prophet Mountain** is, as it were, a promontory rising up through that water. On that mountain, one sees extraordinarily verdant regions broken here and there by deep abysses and ravines full of water. I have, indeed, seen people climbing up the Prophet Mountain, but they did not go far.

No mountain near Jerusalem or Israel fits this possible description: Seeing “people climbing up the Prophet Mountain, but they did not go far” implies an extremely high mountain.

The truth be known, we may never know for sure which mountain is indeed the Mountain of the Prophets!

> Emmerich had many mystical visions which she spoke about. The following seems to be mirrored in many traditions as truth: She wrote, for instance, of ‘a Mount of Prophets, which she clearly identified as the Himalayas, where live Enoch, Elijah and others who did not die in the ordinary way but ascended, and where animals which survived the Flood may also be found'. - [Anne Catherine Emmerich](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_Catherine_Emmerich)

As simple caveat before continuing: On 3 October 2004 Anne Catherine Emmerich was beatified by Pope John Paul II. However, the books produced by Brentano were set aside, and her cause adjudicated solely on the basis of her own personal sanctity and virtue. Peter Gumpel who was involved in the analysis of the matter at the Vatican stated that "since it was impossible to distinguish what derives from Sister Emmerich and what is embroidery or additions, we could not take these writings as a criteria. Therefore, they were simply discarded completely from all the work for the cause". See: [A Movie, a Mystic, a Spiritual Tradition](https://web.archive.org/web/20111005193623/http://americamagazine.org/content/article.cfm?article_id=3481&comments=1)

How the **four rivers** that flowed out of Eden to water the Garden of Eden and from there divides into the four named rivers came to be named as we may never know.

Could it possibly be [Mount Kailash](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Kailash), known also as Mount Meru? This mountain, in some Buddhist texts, seems like a logical point of departure for a general possible location of Eden, if we were to take the Revelations of Blessed Catherine Emmerich to be an actual real account of the Genesis story concerning the Prophet Mountain and the Garden of Eden.

> The mountain is located near Lake Manasarovar and Lake Rakshastal, close to the source of some of the longest Asian rivers: the Indus, Sutlej, Brahmaputra, and Karnali also known as Ghaghara (a tributary of the Ganges) in India. Mount Kailash is considered to be sacred in four religions: Hinduism, Bon, Buddhism, and Jainism. Mount Kailash is considered by many as the central part of the earth surrounded by 6 other mountain ranges from the sides. The campus of Mount Kailash is considered to be the focal point of the whole universe.

Apart from being a beautiful place, Lake Mansarovar is the highest freshwater lake in the world standing at a height of 4,557 meters above sea level, making it one of the highest lakes in the world. The place is best to go deeper into samadhi. Lake Mansarovar is the point of origin of four major rivers namely **Brahmaputra, Ghagra, Sindhu**,and the **Satluj**

Catherine Emmerich at one point made the following remark in her [Revelations](https://archive.org/stream/TheLifeAndRevelationsOfAnneCatherineEmmerichComplete/TheLifeAndRevelationsOfAnneCatherineEmmerich_djvu.txt). The beginnings commences with the visionary’s account of Creation, the Fall of the Angels, the formation of the Earth and Paradise, and the mysterious Mountain of the Prophets. The second part presents Adam and Eve, the Trees of Life and Knowledge, the Fall of Humankind, the Promise of the Redeemer, Cain and Abel, the Children of God, the Giants, Enoch, Noah, the Tower of Babel, and such ancient figures as Hom, Jamshid, Nimrod, Derketo, Semiramis, and Melchizedek, concluding with Job. The third part offers fascinating new insights into the lives and missions of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob.

> Dec. 22. I know why I went to the mountain: my book is among the writings that are on the table: I will be made for me to read the last five leaves. Man sitting at the table will return in time. His chariot stays there as eternal memory. On this chariot he mounted at that height, and men, to their amazement, the will descend on this tank. This is, on this mountain, which is the highest in the world and nobody can happen, what have been secured, when corruption has increased among men, treasures and sacred mysteries. Lake; file, the towers are only available for these treasures are preserved and secured against damage. It is by virtue of the water on this summit is that all things are refreshed and renewed. The river that goes down from there and from which water is the subject of such veneration for the men I’ve seen, really a and strengthens virtue, which is why they consider more than their wines. All men, all goods are down from this height, and all things that should be guaranteed the devastation has been preserved.
>
> Dec. 26. I saw again the mountains of the prophets. The man who is in the tent had a figure from the sky, hovering above him pamphlets and books, and he received other instead. This spirit was different from the first one outside. He who hung in the air reminded me forcibly John. He was more agile, quicker, kinder, more gentle than man in the tent, which was something more energetic, more severe, more strict, more inflexible. The second was related to him as the New Testament to the Old, which is why I would call John and I would call the other Elias. It was as if Elijah had revelations to John who had their accomplishment in and received fresh.

At the moment of creation Eden may have actually been on the highest mountain in the world, but not necessarily Mt. Everest. In any case, the Mountain of the Prophets is east of Jerusalem, in a location filled with mystery and awe. It can not be pin pointed to with any accuracy as God desires it to remain hidden from mankind...

I would like to point out just one liturgical tradition of the Carmelite Order here. The Feast day of the Prophet St. Elijah is celebrated on July 20th. On the day the Carmelites celebrate their liturgical Mass with priests donning red coloured vestments. According to Catholic tradition Elijah is one of the two witnesses mentioned in the Apocalypse of St. John the will be martyred in Jerusalem in the end days. Early Christian writers such as Tertullian, Irenaeus, and Hippolytus of Rome, have concluded that the two witnesses would be Enoch and Elijah, the two prophets who did not die because God "took" them according to various Biblical passages.

This is my own take on this mysterious possibility as to where the Mountain of the Prophets may be located. Other opinions surely exist.

According to Catherine Emmerich the Garden of Eden and the Prophet Mountain are not far apart.

Remember what Bl. Catherine Emmerich stated about this Prophet Mountain: The Prophet Mountain and just where the sun rises. It looks to me like an egg hanging over indescribably clear water which separates it from the earth.

[image]

[Mount Kailash—the Stairway to Heaven](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/travel/destinations/mount-kailash-facts-mindboggling-things-you-may-not-know-about-lord-shivas-home/articleshow/61220500.cms)

**Due to its religious significance and local veneration, Mt. Kailash remains an unclimbed mountain to this day.**